# Unable to Query DynamoDB Table from Lambda Function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

Receive the error when executing a Lambda function:

> "AccessDeniedException: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::342213474092:assumed-role/testServerlessStack-ExecRole-YZCIWMHK86D8/testServerlessStack-GetFailureKeysByOrder-OR3YS1NLQY0M
>   is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:342213474092:table/Bar"

The function's execution role has the following permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:342213474092:table/Foo/*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:342213474092:table/Bar/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Lambda queries `Foo` then scans `Bar`.

Comment: It looks like you have different account numbers in the permissions (dynamodb table ARNs), is that intentional?

Comment: They match. All the resources (Lambda and DynamoDB tables) are in the same account.

Comment: I think the problem is in my resource specification, but I can't find docs on that piece of the IAM permission.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, the resources should be formatted as:

To query a table:
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name

or:
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/*

The same goes for scan:

To scan a table:
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name

or:
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/*

Have you tried changing the resources to:

```
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:342213474092:table/Foo",
            "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:342213474092:table/Bar"
        ],
```

Docs here: [DynamoDB API permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html)

Based on your last comment, this should work for you:

```
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/*/index/*
```

Comment: The tables I'm querying have indexes. When I adjust the resource names as you've suggested (and it's a good idea), I get failures on the indexes I'm querying. But, if I were to change the resources to "*" (asterisk). It works fine. So, to skip ahead, how can I configure this access without enumerating each table and index or using an asterisk?

Comment: The docs show:

arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/index-name

or:
arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/table-name/index/*

for an index, so theoretically you could use:

arn:aws:dynamodb:region:account-id:table/*/index/*

Comment: That's still using an asterisk, but not at the top resources level.

Comment: That's a little too permissive. I was trying to lock the operations down by table. I ended up with something like the following:
`arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:642113479024:table/Foo` and 
`arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:642113479024:table/Foo/index/*` I had to do this for each table that use an index and table. I could lock it down to the specific index, but that's too much maintenance for me.